# Installing 32bit app on 64bit Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 64-bit, 15.10, 32-bit, shared-library

I tried to install 32bit linux app (Cadsoft Eagle) on 64bit Ubuntu 15.10 via terminal. This was the result:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I already have installed many libraries for 32bit support.

When I try to install this package (`sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386`), the result is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl0.9.8:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl0.9.8:i386' has no installation candidate
```

What can I do?

Comment: How about `sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8` ? see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/77256/i-want-to-install-libssl-0-9-8

Comment: try to check the package with `sudo apt-cache search libssl-` to see the exact package.

Comment: Tshilidzi Mudau - it doesn't work, either. Same result.

Comment: AzkerM - it found many packages including this, but in 1.0.0 version `libssl1.0.0 - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libssl0.9.8 is no longer available in ubuntu 15.10 repositories.
You can download and install manually the deb file from this link if you want [libssl0.9.8](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/precise/amd64/libssl0.9.8/download) (clic on the link "security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu" when you reach that page).

you can install the package downloaded by copying the deb file in your home folder, then open a terminal and enter this command `sudo dpkg -i libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb`

Comment: I opened the file (in QApt Package Installer) and I cannot click on the "Install Package" button.

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2_amd64 (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2_amd64

Comment: the error you entered means you misspelled the package or gave a wrong path. make sure that the package is in your home directory and don't misspell his name in the command.

Comment: oh my mistake, now it worked. When i run command  `sudo apt-cache search libssl`, it finds `libssl0.9.8 - SSL shared libraries`, but when I try to install eagle, it returns the exactly same error.

Comment: may be you need to install the i386 package, you can download it from this link http://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/precise/libssl0.9.8 (choose the i386 version).

Comment: Yeah,  thank you. After that, I installed one more package and the installator is working properly :)